# Backend code is working fine on localhost but Heroku gives me errors

Tags: node.js, heroku, deployment, backend, heroku-cli

I'm trying to deploy my backend code on Heroku for learning purposes. Deployment on Heroku, according to the dashboard is successful but when I'm trying to open the app, it throws an error. I did the `heroku logs --tail` and it showed me this error:
[image]

I tried running the code on localhost and no error is found. Any leads is greatly appreciated.

Comment: Heroku start script is probably missing, the error message H10 indicates that, try adding heroku post build script.

Answer (score 0):

"App crashed" isn't very specific when it comes to errors...
One thing I can advice you to do is to try using InfinityFree if you're a student trying to test your app.
It's very easy and always works my app the same way LocalHost does it.

I hope this helps if you don't find a fix for your issue.

Answer (score 0):

code H10 has to do with a server issues. I had this same error when working with some pre existing code.

```
const PORT = process.env.PORT || 3001;
```

Every time I ran localhost it would do the OR operator and just run on 3001 so no issues on the backend with local host but would error out on heroku. I discovered my issue was I forgot to install a couple dependencies specifically mongodb and mongoose. Double check your server app and make sure what you are using is correctly installed. In my case it was using mongodb and mongoose, yours might not be the same but you may have forgot to install the dependencies for whatever you're using.

I ran:
$ npm install mongodb --save
$ npm install mongoose
$ git add .
$ git commit -am "installed dependencies"
$ git push heroku main

Then I just refreshed my app and it worked.